# Have Blazor InputText keep focus after submitting

Tags: forms, focus, blazor

I'm building a little chat widget to my Blazor app. It works too, but to make it work more fluently, I'd like to make the focus stay in the InputText after submitting a message.

Any time I press enter, the message gets sent and received correctly. Unfortunately, the focus also goes wherever. This doesn't let you quickly type multiple messages into the chat.

I guess I could make a JS interop method sending the focus back to the InputText and call that after every submit, but I'd prefer to find a js-free solution.

My Razor markup is this:

```
<EditForm Model="message" OnSubmit="SendMessage">
    <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="message.Message" />
</EditForm>
```

I send the message like this:

```
private async Task SendMessage()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Send message " + message.Message);
    var t = Service.SendMessage(message);
    messages.Add(message);
    message = new Library.Models.ChatMessage();
    await t;
    Console.WriteLine("Sending finished.");
}
```

Comment: As of the last I checked, JS interop was the way to go for SetFocus. Just be sure the target element is rendered before you set the focus. As a thought, in a project I am working on I built up a very small service that gets the IJSRuntime through DI and exposes a couple of methods, one of which is focus. All of this is wrapping the JS method, so it's easier to access through c# code. To use it I pass in an element id and focus is set after execution, dead simple and not a lot of work to set up. This is likely your ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not normally happen in an HTML form. The loss of focus is caused by the re-rendering of the tree.

As a workaround, not real pretty:

```
private async Task SendMessage()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Send message " + message.Message);
    var copy = new Library.Models.ChatMessage { Message = message.Message };
    var t = Service.SendMessage(copy);
    messages.Add(copy); 
    // message = new Library.Models.ChatMessage(); -- this was the problem
    message.Message = "";
    await t;
    Console.WriteLine("Sending finished.");
}
```

I experimented a little with `@key` but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Nice, I'm gonna try this once I'm off work! You think replacing the whole message makes the tree rerender? I'd be totally happy with using this approach. Or I use a struct, which would make the copying inherent.

Comment: Yes, it works. I ran a little test. Something is hooked on the Identity of the Model here.